Eliminating particular cells in an array in Python
I am scraping to get the ISBN codes of certain books online. Sometimes, when I search for book titles I can find titles that are no the ones I want.
For instance, searching on isbndb.com for  "The third bear Jeff VanderMeer" gives 4 books back, having the first one the tile of "The Year's Top Ten Tales of Science Fiction", which is not what I want. The remaining 3 books are ok, since all have the desired title but for different editions.
I have an array with titles, in the form:
aux_title = 
[" The Year's Top Ten Tales of Science Fiction",
 ' The Third Bear',
 ' The Third Bear',
 ' The Third Bear']

And I created a binary array that takes the value of 1 if the title is actually the one I want, using the get_close_matches function. The array is:
match_names =
[0., 1., 1., 1.]

I want to write a code that looks at the match_names, and elimiantes the elements in aux_title that have it correspondent value in match_names to e 0. The outcome I want would be"
[' The Third Bear',
 ' The Third Bear',
 ' The Third Bear']

This should be done for all the 22k titles I have, when sometimes we have tens of different titles and we want to keep only the ones very close to the original one. I guess this is done by a very simple way, but I cannot figure how. I'm thinking on a function such as 'find' in matlab, but don't know which is it here.

You can use numpy (as hinted by tag you have applied) following way
import numpy as np
aux_title =  np.array([" The Year's Top Ten Tales of Science Fiction",' The Third Bear',' The Third Bear',' The Third Bear'])
match_names = np.array([0., 1., 1., 1.])
selected_titles = aux_title[match_names==1.0]
print(selected_titles)

which gives output
[' The Third Bear' ' The Third Bear' ' The Third Bear']

Considering your intended usage you would probably need to find threshold which works for you use case, e.g. if you consider at least 0.5 as pointing desired titles you might express that in numpy as
selected_titles = aux_title[match_names>=0.5]


my_titles = [x for i,x in zip(match_names, aux_title) if i==1.0]

That is: make a list of the second part of elements from combining the 2 lists where the first part is 1.
